# "We're sorry, but you have sent too many requests to us recently. Please try again later."

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

> "We're sorry, but you have sent too many requests to us recently. Please try again later."

I got this when trying to open a Google Spreadsheets.

All my other spreadsheets work.

Any solutions here?